# Lego RCX 1.0 brick relationship to Robotics Invention System (RIS) & RCX firmware versions

Tags: rcx

What is the relationship between a Lego RCX 1.0 brick and these:

Robotics Invention System (RIS) versions

- 1.0
- 1.5
- 2.0

RCX firmware:

- firm0309.lgo: RCX firmware version 3.09
- firm0328.lgo: RCX firmware version 3.28
- firm0332.lgo: RCX firmware version 3.32

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant hardware difference (*) affecting software between the RCX bricks, so 1.0 brick is compatible with all firmware and RIS versions.

(*) Known hardware differences:

- RCX 1.0 sold with RIS 1.0 had a power adapter plug.
- RCX 1.0 sold with RIS 1.5 no longer had this plug.
- RCX 2.0 had a 76 kHz IR interface instead of 38 kHz. It remains compatible with old versions (harmonic 2) albeit with a slightly
  reduced range. New frequency allows to communicate with Spybots bricks.

Comment: Doesn't the earlier RCX 1.0 brick have a power adapter plug, which has been eliminated in the RCX 1.0 brick supplied with RIS 1.5 and in the RCX 2.0 brick supplied in RIS 2.0?

Comment: Yes it does, but doesn't matter for software. Answer edited for more details!

Answer (score 2):

The main differences between the versions were:

1. Firmware - although later versions of the firmware were backwards compatible with the earlier bricks
2. Power Adaptors:

   1. RIS/RCX 1.0 had a power socket on the brick as well as battery options
   2. RIS/RCX 1.5 removed the power socket from the brick
   3. RIS/RCX 2.0 Functionally equivalent to RCX 1.5
3. IR Tower connections:

   1. RIS 1.0 and 1.5 had a serial connection for the IR Tower
   2. RIS 2.0 had a USB connection for the IR Tower, which doesn't operate nicely with 64bit Operating Systems (ironically* the serial connection does work with a serial-USB adaptor apparently)
4. Manuals - I [believe the Constructopedia was more comprehensive](http://www.ebay.co.uk/gds/LEGO-Mindstorms-A-Basic-Guide-to-the-Older-RCX-sets-/10000000000766046/g.html) in 1.0 than in 2.0.

`*` I say ironically as I originally returned my 1.0 or 1.5 set as I was unable to get the serial connection to work on my PC at the time and later bought a 2.0 which worked fine then, but not any more on my more modern hardware.